# Cannot get Updated android library version from Jcenter

Tags: android

I have distribute my library project in Jcenter,my last library version is 4.0.8 was published in the month of  DEC 2016.Now I have updated my library with few changes as 4.0.9 and also received BUID SUCESSFULL message but but there is no updates from jcenter repo still showing 4.0.8

Comment: Try clean your project and build it again. May be it use the previous version lib try to clean the project.

Comment: Hi thanks for ur reply. Have tried that but no use

Comment: same issue. Have you found solution?